# WPF - Advice on using a treeview style menu structure

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF. I'm moving a a Win Forms application over to WPF, which requires a lot of learning on my part.

In WinForms, I would create a subclass of common controls (MyLabel : Label, MyDataGrid : DataGrid, etc)
This would allow me to set all my required attributes and styles, and these would be consistent for any control I then used. In addition, I could implement functionality on these controls that would be available for all my controls.

I'm failing miserably at being able to do this with a TreeView/TreeViewItem in WPF. 
I created a working example with a normal TreeView, and then simply substituted MyTreeView in the MainPage. I get:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.'

Hopefully you can download a project from this link:
https://app.box.com/s/9ofyuwfgk2cobqhokezgkknvtnmzmeq7

Part of the design change is to implement the menu as a treeview on the left of the screen. This will have approximately 60 options.

I've spent a bit of time, and have a populated TreeView. 
However, I believe it is possible to use a menu here, and style it as a tree view. Is this correct?
If so, can anyone point me to an example, as I haven't been able to find one on Google. Google seems to think I want a context menu on a TreeView.

Edited to add code:

TreeView xaml (TreeViewItem is basically identical)

```
    <TreeView x:Class="WpfApp1.Controls.MyTreeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
        <Grid>
        </Grid>
    </TreeView>
```

TreeView cs

```
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    namespace WpfApp1.Controls
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MyTreeView.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MyTreeView : TreeView
        {
            public MyTreeView()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

        protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
        {
            return new MyTreeView();
        }

        protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
        {
            return item is MyTreeView;
        }
    }
```

MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="treeViewStructure" Source="Data/treeViewStructure.xml" XPath="./*/Category"/>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Category" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="SubCategory" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Controls:MyTreeView x:Name="mainTreeViewMenu"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      BorderThickness="0"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource treeViewStructure}}" DataContext="{DynamicResource treeViewStructure}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Changing Controls:MyTreeView to simply TreeView will enable the app to run normally

ETA2: XML for Bradley:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Categories>
    <Category Name="1">
      <SubCategory Name="A"/>
      <SubCategory Name="B"/>
    </Category>
    <Category Name="2">
      <SubCategory Name="C"/>
      <SubCategory Name="D"/>
      <SubCategory Name="E"/>
      <SubCategory Name="F"/>
      <SubCategory Name="G"/>
      <SubCategory Name="H"/>
    </Category>
    <Category Name="3">
      <SubCategory Name="I"/>
      <SubCategory Name="J"/>
    </Category>
    <Category Name="4">
      <SubCategory Name="K"/>
      <SubCategory Name="L"/>
    </Category>
  </Categories>
```

Comment: That's because the "menu" class is typically used for context menus. You wouldn't use one to replace a tree view. Also, please post the relevant code here. We can't help you as is

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found a post on here (can't find it now) that suggested styling a menu as a treeview, rather than trying to use a treeview as a menu.
Will add the code directly now.

Comment: Setting the data context on the tree view like that is super odd. I would try removing that. Other than that I don't see an obvious source of your exception.

Comment: You're adding a `<Grid>` as a child control of your TreeView, and an empty one at that. That's the source of your exception, what were you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also keep in mind that WPF has been specifically designed so that subclassing windows controls is rarely needed. Matthew McDonalds excellent book "Pro WPF in C#" has this to say: "In previous Windows development frameworks, custom controls played a central role. But in WPF, the
emphasis has shifted. Custom controls are still a useful way to build custom widgets that you can share
between applications, but they’re no longer a requirement when you want to enhance and customize
core controls.....

Comment: ...(To understand how remarkable this change is, it helps to point out that this book’s
predecessor, Pro .NET 2.0 Windows Forms and Custom Controls in C#, had nine complete chapters about
custom controls and additional examples in other chapters. But in this book, you’ve made it to Chapter
18 without a single custom control sighting!)"

Comment: @MarkFeldman I'm coming from WinForms, so that's the main problem.

I'm simply trying to sub class TreeView, as I would in WinForms, so that I understand how that works. 

You are right though, the problem was the empty <Grid>. Removing that fixed the error.

I think I'll order that book and have a proper read.

Thanks

Comment: @MarkFeldman Looks like I was a little optimistic.
Removing the empty <Grid> fixed the error, and the app now runs, but the treeview has no text.
I *think* I need to add a style, but I'm not sure. 

Any ideas? 

Book ordered, but I'd like to get this working.
All I'm trying to do is get MyTreeView to display as it it's a TreeView.
If the correct answer is "You don't need to do that in WPF", please just say that.

Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I don't even understand which bit is odd. Can you be more specific? 

I want to have a simple XML file in a Data folder that I bind to the TreeView. 
I've added it above. Feel free to let me know if there's a better way to structure it.

Comment: Having never used XmlDataProvider, I would probably start with something *way* simpler; say a collection of in memory objects, to make sure my tree view was correct

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks. I hard coded some items in the MainWindow.xaml, and it behaved the same. 
At least this proves I need to add some further set up in my MyTreeView/MyTreeViewItems to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

A few mistakes in your code, but you're close. The thing to keep in mind is that things like `DataType` are used when you've serialized your XML data into a specific type of class. You don't get the benefits of this when you use XmlDataProvider, the data all gets serialized into generic XML data classes so you have to do things a bit differently to most of the example TreeView code you'll find on the net.

In your case you need to specifically bind all the root elements to a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` resource that you declare with a key, and then have that bind to the list of children via XPath again. This should do this trick:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="treeViewStructure" Source="Data/treeViewStructure.xml" />

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SubCategory">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Category" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=SubCategory}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SubCategory}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <!-- force all treeviewitems to be initially expanded -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<TreeView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource treeViewStructure}, XPath=/Categories/Category}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Category}" />
```

Result:

[image]

Also if you don't explicitly need different templates for each node then you can just use the one, WPF will figure out that your children don't have children themselves:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Category" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=SubCategory}" >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```